# Transferring data from MySQL database to iOS device safely

Tags: php, mysql, ios, database, json

I am trying to build an iOS application that will pass data back and forth from the web server (or the database directly).  There is very sensitive information being passed (like money information and passwords).  In the past I have used JSON to connect to a database before using php files that use GET functions.  I thought about using POST - but both seem pretty unsafe.  Is there a better way?  I have never worked with such sensitive information.

Comment: Use HTTPS instead of HTTP to communicate to the server.

Comment: You could potentially encrypt the information which your application receives from the PHP back-end. Decrypt it with the key in the app.

Answer (score 1):

Use simple protocol like REST and JSON. For iOS you can use Rest client like RestKit that makes it much easier to handle GETs and POSTs. Use HTTP Authentication - RestKit handles http authentication like basic authentication easly and transparently.
Use HTTPS to hide content from sniffing. 
You can also encrypt critical parts of payload additionally if paranoid :)